# Nextjs react hook form submit not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form, zod

I use nextjs react hook form and zod it works fine in register and login but when I tried to make profile settings and it's also work but when I decied to create switch between user register (hasPassword) and user oauth (!hasPassword) so if user has password then inputs of password display and he can change his password, then react hook form submit doesn't work again without give me any errors.

in types.ts:

```
export const settings = z.object({
    name: z.string().min(3).max(32).regex(/^[a-zA-Z\s.]+$/),
    email: z.string().email(),
    password: z.union([z.string().length(0), z.string()]).transform(e => e === "" ? undefined : e),
    npassword: z.union([z.string()
        .min(8, "New Password must have more than 8 characte")
        .max(32, "Password is so long must have low than 32 characters"),
    z.string().length(0), ]).transform(e => e === "" ? undefined : e),
    cpassword: z.union([z.string().length(0), z.string()]).transform(e => e === "" ? undefined : e)
}).superRefine((val, ctx) => {
    if(val.npassword && !val.password) {
        ctx.addIssue({
            code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
            message: `Old Password is required.`,
            path: ["password"]
        })
    }

    if(!val.npassword && val.password) {
        ctx.addIssue({
            code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
            path: ["npassword"]
        })
    }

    if(val.npassword !== val.cpassword) {
        ctx.addIssue({
            code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
            message: `Must match new Password`,
            path: ["cpassword"]
        })
    }
})
```

in Form.tsx:

```
"use client"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { settings } from "@/libs/types"
import { z } from "zod"
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod"
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"
import { Button } from "@nextui-org/react"
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
import { useState } from "react"

export default function Form() {
    const [error, setError] = useState("")
    const {data: session} = useSession()
    const route = useRouter()

    type settingTypes = z.infer<typeof settings>

    const {
        handleSubmit,
        register,
        formState: {errors, isValid, isSubmitting, dirtyFields},
    } = useForm<settingTypes>({defaultValues: {
        name: session?.user.name,
        email: session?.user.email,
        password: undefined,
        npassword: undefined,
        cpassword: undefined
    },
        resolver: zodResolver(settings),
    })

    const styleInp = "p-3 border-1 w-full placeholder:text-primary placeholder:text-opacity-60 outline-none focus:outline-2 focus:outline-offset-0 dark:shadow-md rounded-md"

    const onSubmit = async (data: settingTypes) => {
        setError("")
        try {
            if(isValid) {
                /* const req = await fetch('/api/settings', {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                })
    
                const res = await req.json()
    
                if(!req.ok) {
                    setError(res.error)
                    return
                }
    
                route.refresh()
                return */
                console.log(data)
            }
          } catch (e) {
            setError("Something went wrong... come back later")
          }
    }

  return (
    <div className="bg-white text-primary dark:bg-black dark:text-white bg-opacity-50 dark:bg-opacity-20 w-full h-full rounded-xl p-6 text-sm sm:text-md">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className={`flex flex-col ${session?.user.hasPassword ? "sm:flex-row" : "" } gap-6 h-full`}>
            <div className={`${session?.user.hasPassword ? "sm:w-1/2" : "md:w-3/4 lg:w-1/2" } space-y-2 sm:space-y-4`}>
                <div className="flex flex-col items-start sm:gap-2">
                    <label htmlFor="name" className="p-1">Change Name</label>
                    <input defaultValue={session?.user.name} {...register("name")} placeholder={"Enter new name"} type="text" className={`${styleInp} focus:outline-primary border-primary border-opacity-40`} />
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col items-start sm:gap-2">
                    <label htmlFor="email" className="p-1">Your Email</label>
                    <input defaultValue={session?.user.email} {...register("email")} type="email" disabled className={`${styleInp} disabled:text-slate-400 select-none disabled:dark:text-slate-500 disabled:bg-slate-300 disabled:dark:bg-slate-800 border-opacity-5 border-primary dark:border-default"}`} />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={`${session?.user.hasPassword ? "sm:w-1/2 h-full sm:flex flex-col items-between justify-between" : "h-full" }`}>
                    {session?.user.hasPassword
                    ? <div className="space-y-2 sm:space-y-4 sm:mb-6">
                        <div className="flex flex-col items-start sm:gap-2">
                            <label htmlFor="password" className="p-1">Old Password</label>
                            <input {...register("password")} placeholder={"Enter your old Password"} type="password" className={`${styleInp} ${errors.password ? "focus:outline-danger border-danger" : "focus:outline-primary border-primary border-opacity-40"}`} />
                            {errors.password && <p className="text-danger p-1">{errors.password.message}</p>}
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex flex-col items-start sm:gap-2">
                            <label htmlFor="npassword" className="p-1">New Password</label>
                            <input {...register("npassword")} placeholder={"Enter your new Password"} type="password" className={`${styleInp} ${dirtyFields.npassword && errors.npassword ? "focus:outline-danger border-danger" : "focus:outline-primary border-primary border-opacity-40"}`} />
                            {dirtyFields.npassword && errors.npassword && <p className="text-danger p-1">{errors.npassword.message}</p>}
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex flex-col items-start sm:gap-2">
                            <label htmlFor="cpassword" className="p-1">Confirm New Password</label>
                            <input {...register("cpassword")} placeholder={"Confirm your new Password"} type="password" className={`${styleInp} ${errors.cpassword ? "focus:outline-danger border-danger" : "focus:outline-primary border-primary border-opacity-40"}`} />
                            {errors.cpassword && <p className="text-danger p-1">{errors.cpassword.message}</p>}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    : ""}
                <div className="pt-4">
                    {error && <p className="px-2 text-danger text-end">{error}</p>}
                    <div className="flex pt-2 gap-3 justify-end">
                        <Button onClick={() => route.back()} color="default">Cancel</Button>
                        <Button disabled={Object.keys(dirtyFields).length === 0 || isSubmitting} className="disabled:opacity-40 disabled:hover:opacity-40" type="submit" color="primary">Save Change</Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I tried to remove :

```
password: undefined,
npassword: undefined,
cpassword: undefined
```

from defaultValues but didn't work and I tried to remove

```
session?.user.hasPassword
```

condition but still not work

Comment: You said the form submit doesn't work- have you tried checking the network calls to see if there is at least a call being made? Something has to happen once you click the button.

Comment: No nothing happens it's clear